# git , how to accept rm file update without delete the file?

Tags: git

I have a `local_settings.py` in my django prject, which is a custom settings different by each dev.
Yesterday, I mistake to commit `conf/local_settings.py` to repo and push to bitbucket. This project is new, I think it can not rollback because the file was committed at first push, 
I remove `local_settings.py` from repo without delete by `git rm --cached ./conf/local_settings.py`.That works on local machine.

I meet a error when I do git pull on my vps.

```
.....
>>> git pull origin master
Updating f1d56d3..6163ffb
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        conf/local_settings.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

How can I make others would not delete their `local_settings.py` after pulling the repo and update the code automatically? I am new to git , so I am afraid something would go wrong if others do merge themself in this case.

**my case example:**

A  has `local_settings.py` , B has `local_settings.py`, they all use `origin master`.

1. A git init , push all files. B pull. A, B change their `local_settings.py` , it is different.
2. A find `local_settings.py` should not be in repo.
3. A `git rm --cached ./conf/local_settings.py`, and push this commit.
4. (What I need) B pull, remove `local_settings.py` from B local repo without delete it.

Comment: You said "This project is new", can I assume that no one has pulled your change of mistakenly committed local_settings.py yet? If so, why not just amend the previous commit and push again?

Comment: @AdrianShum Shum I mean this project is new add to git. Project's code are already exists in several my vps. I am new to use git to update the project.

Comment: hm... I read several times but still don't get what you are trying to say in the comment.  Let me take it this way: has anyone pulled your wrong commit from bitbucket yet?

Comment: @Adrian Shum sorry for my poor English. Yes, I pull commit on two of my vps. Because code is already exists , I use `git fetch --all`  , `git reset --hard origin/master` to force pull.

Answer (score 2):

Other developers won't be able to pull a version that contains `local_settings.py` because Git knows it would overwrite their (untracked) version. After you remove it and push the removal, then other developers will be able to pull again.

Comment: I have pushed the removal,  but pulling the repo occur error.

Answer (score 0):

(I guess I am talking about the same thing as the answer from Greg Hewgill)

```
      master
        *
.... <- A
```

Assuming you have the above repo

What you have done is you committed incorrectly your `local_setting.py` and pushed to the central repo, which makes it:

```
           master
             *
.... <- A <- B
```

(B contains `local_setting.py`)

What you have tried to fix is by

```
               master
                 *
... <- A <- B <- C
```

(C contains git rm `local_setting.py`)
hence you have need to force overwrite etc

As repositories that has pulled the change is still under your control, and there should be no commit after `C`, what you should do to fix is

1. reset `master` to `B` (the commit that you have `local_setting.py` commited)

   ```
             master
               *
   ... <- A <- B <- C
   ```
2. Make use of git commit --amend to fix your "previous commit" (which is B) by not including `local_settings.py`

   ```
   ... <- A <- B <- C
          ^  master
          |    *
           \-- B'
   ```

and push to your central repo.

Please note, if there are other commit after `C` by anyone, this approach will not work.